# React: import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; error

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm using the reactstrap library, Successfully installed the bootstrap and reactstrap

however when i use `import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` react won't compile. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the following import statement - without the `node_modules/` and you should get around this issue

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7qpgyj)

Comment: just.. additional, is it necessary to modify the webpack.config.js  {
                test:/\.css$/,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            },